# How to get a list of Window Rectangle from EnumChildWindow and store them?

Tags: c++, vector, rectangles, enumerate, childwindow

I used `EnumChildWindows` and I can get the `Handle`, `ClassName` and `WindowText` of all the child windows. But I also want to get all the child windows' `Rectangle`. Is it possible?

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char class_name[100];
    char title[100];

    GetClassNameA(hwnd,class_name, sizeof(class_name));
    GetWindowTextA(hwnd,title,sizeof(title));

    cout <<"Window name : "<<title<<endl;
    cout <<"Class name  : "<<class_name<<endl;
    cout <<"hwnd        : "<<hwnd<<endl<<endl;
                                                   
    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    POINT pt;
    Sleep(3000);

    GetCursorPos(&pt);
    HWND hwnd = WindowFromPoint(pt);
    HWND hwndParent = GetParent(hwnd);

    EnumChildWindows(hwndParent,EnumWindowsProc,0);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Also, how can I stored all the data (handle,classname,windowtext,rectangle) of each child windows? Maybe in a vector list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, you may have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect).

For your second question, you may define a structure with the fields you need, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>

struct MyWindow {
 HWND handle_;
 std::string name_;
 std::string text_;
 RECT rect_;
 MyWindow(HWND handle, const std::string& name, const std::string& text, RECT rect): handle_{handle}, name_{name}, text_{text}, rect_{rect}{}
};

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char name[100];
    char text[100];
    RECT rect{0};

    GetClassNameA(hwnd,name, sizeof(name));
    GetWindowTextA(hwnd,text,sizeof(text));
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);

    std::vector<MyWindow>* myVec = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<MyWindow>*>(lParam);

    if (myVec) {
      myVec->emplace_back(MyWindow(hwnd, std::string(name), std::string(text), rect));
    } else {
      // Pointer to vector is NULL, handle accordingly
     return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    POINT pt;
    Sleep(3000);

    std::vector<MyWindow> myChildWindows;

    GetCursorPos(&pt);
    HWND hwnd = WindowFromPoint(pt);
    HWND hwndParent = GetParent(hwnd);

    EnumChildWindows(hwndParent, EnumWindowsProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&myChildWindows));

    for (const auto & childWindow: myChildWindows) {
            std::cout <<"Window name : "<< childWindow.name_ << std::endl;
            std::cout <<"Class name  : "<< childWindow.text_<< std::endl;
            std::cout <<"hwnd        : "<< childWindow.handle_<< std::endl;
            std::cout << "Rect: " << childWindow.rect_.left << "/" << childWindow.rect_.right << std::endl;
            std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

I added a bit more code and explanation. This example should compile and run just fine.

`std::vector` is a sequence container that encapsulates dynamic size arrays [1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

When you declare `myChildWindows` in the main function, it is initialized to an empty vector, that can contain Objects of Type `MyWindow`. You can add and remove objects to that vector dynamically, i.e. you do not have to specify the size of the vector at compile time, like for example with an array. We then pass the pointer to this vector to your callback `EnumWindowsProc`. In this callback, we use this pointer to add Objects of type `MyWindow` to the vector. When `EnumChildWindows` returns, we can have a look at our vector by printing every object contained in the vector.

Comment: Hi, for the 1st question, I'm able to use `GetWindowRect` to get the `Rect` of the window that I pointed on only. I'm trying to get and show them as a list that similar to the others (windowname, classname, hwnd).
for the 2nd question, is it possible to make it more details? Sorry to say that I'm new to `std::vector` and I'm not sure how to implement your example. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I failed to compile it, **For** `MyWindow(HWND handle, const std::string& name, const std::string& text, RECT rect): handle_{handle}, name_{name}, text_{text}, rect_{rect}{}
}` errors are _syntax error : ','_  and  _unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body_  **For** `RECT rect{0};` error is _'rect' : local function definitions are illegal_ .   There are other errors more...

Comment: How are you compiling it?

Comment: I'm using VisualStudio Win32 Project to compile it

Comment: Are you sure you have no typos in your code? I compiled it using cygwin and and Visual Studio Code and it works both times

Comment: I copy exactly from here. I tried to run on cygwin and it works. Might be my VisualStudio issue

Comment: Hi @sfun, the reason of syntax error could be the different version of visual studio. I'm using Visual Studio 2008 to compile it. Is there any reference to refer to make it able to be compiled in VS2008? Thanks.